# Orientation of a navigationController in a TabBarController doesn't work like it should

Tags: objective-c, orientation, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

This is the situation
[image]

The label-viewcontroller is able to change orientation, the viewcontroller with the "ok?"-button is only able to be viewed in portrait. This works PERFECT, when I'm at the label-viewcontroller, in landscape, and I go back to the "ok?"-viewcontroller it automatically switches to portrait. like it should.
But the thing is, I want the "Ok?"-Viewcontroller to be viewed in landscape, not in portrait. When I do this, it doesn't work annymore... When I'm in the label-viewcontroller and i go back it doesn't change to landscape...

So... 
When I put the "ok?"viewcontroller in portrait it works, but when I put it in landscape it doesn't, why is this and how can I solve this?

Works, but I don't need it this way.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);

 }
```

Doesn't work but I need it to work.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

 }
```

The label-viewcontroller is simply.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     return YES;
 }
```

and the TabBarController.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
 }
```

sorry for the bad english

Comment: Nobody? Really could use some help. :)